# How do i put some text below icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put text below some icons but it ends up being after it, like in the hyperlink below. I tried to use span but the text was just invisible and ive been struggling for about 1 hour now.

How it looks:

[image: How it looks]

But this is how i want it to look:

[image: How i want it to look]

Here's the code:

```css
.services-col {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 1);
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 180px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.services-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="services-col">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <h3>Refurbishing</h3>
</div>
<div class="services-col">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-hammer"></i></div>
  <h3>Construction</h3>
</div>
<div class="services-col">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <h3>Designing</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: simply add the <h3>  below the container div...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to absolutely position the text outside the container by using a `top:100%` top position the h3 passed the bottom of the div, and applying a `position: relative` to your service-cols. This is a bit clumsy though...

```css
.services-col{
    min-width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background: rgba(255,99,71,1);
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0 180px;
    position:relative;
}
h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position:absolute;
    top: 100%;
}

.services-col:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
    <div class="services-col">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></div> 
        <h3>Refurbishing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-hammer"></i></div>    
        <h3>Construction</h3>      
    </div>
    <div class="services-col">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <h3>Designing</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It solves the issue but I will not up-vote it as it is indeed clumsy. If you want to absolute position the text (which might cause unintended collision behaviors) then you should position it below the circle by using `top: 100%` as property and value to palce it below the relative parent. No need for fixed negative margins.

Comment: @tacoshy I considered top: 100% and removing the margins/padding from the h3, but I already feel dirty doing it this way anyway. :D

Comment: There you go, top:100%, still hate it. I totally agree the structure of the HTML is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

your html structure is incorrect

```css
.services-col {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 1);
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 180px;
}

.col{
display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;}

h3 {
  
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.services-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#container{
display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div class='col'>
  <div class="services-col"></div>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <h3>Refurbishing</h3>
</div>
  
  
  
<div class='col'>  
  <div class="services-col"></div>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-hammer"></i></div>
    <h3>Construction</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='col'>
  <div class="services-col"></div>
    <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <h3>Designing</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend wrapping another div around the icon, separating the text from the circle. You will need to add some styling to the box. For example:

```css
 .services-col {
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 1);
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
 }
    
.box {
  width: 150px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.services-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="services-col">
        <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    </div>

    <h3>Refurbishing</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly as @DCR did. Sorry I was being slow editing, didn't mean to post same results =)

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a extra container.

```css
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.services-col {
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 1);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 180px;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.services-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="services-col-wrapper">
        <div class="services-col">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Refurbishing</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col-wrapper">
        <div class="services-col">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-hammer"></i></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Construction</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="services-col-wrapper">
        <div class="services-col">
            <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        </div>
        <h3>Designing</h3>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code can help:

```css
body{
  
}

.services-col {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: rgba(255, 99, 71, 1);
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0px 180px 60px 180px;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position:  absolute;
  top: 150px;
}

.services-col:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="services-col">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-wrench" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <h3>Refurbishing</h3>
</div>
<div class="services-col">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-hammer"></i></div>
  <h3>Construction</h3>
</div>
<div class="services-col">
  <div class="icon"><i class="fa-solid fa-ruler" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <h3>Designing</h3>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is because you are centering your text and icon within your div

```
.services-col{
    ...
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    ...
}
```

Comment: just a random guess that is not even close. Centering the icon is intended.

Comment: I understand. I would put the elements in separate divs and center the icon in its own div.